# How to consider first row of CSV file as header in python csv.reader

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I want to read first and 8th row of csv file and store it in dataframe, I want to have first row as data frame column header, how to do it. Below is the code.

```
with open('D://Sunil_Work//temp8//temp//WID_AM_MacroData.csv') as fd:
 reader=csv.reader(fd,delimiter=';')
 data=pd.DataFrame(([row for idx, row in enumerate(reader) if idx in (0,7)]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(file_path).loc[[1, 8]]
```

This should work.

Comment: But I want to read only first and 8th row, so I have used above script, for entire csv import 'pd.read_csv' will work fine.